# A simple Congruence Equation

Tags: modules, congruences, congruence-relations

I know how to find $56x\equiv 101$ or solve two or more equations with the chineese remainder theorem, but how do I solve equation with a big power?

$$x^{31}\equiv 2(mod81) | x\in \mathbb{Z}_{81}$$
Is the solving technique based on the chineese remainder theorem or it something else?

Comment: Try using Fermat's Little theorem.

Comment: Did you mean Euler's theorem or Fermat's ?
Sinsirely, I thought about it and I don't see how to use it here.$$$$
Because Fermat's theorem talks about a prime number and some another number, and Euler's theorem about any two coprime numbers. 
All I know to say is by Euler, $\phi(81)=54$ and that is the first thing I was asked in the question.

Comment: Sorry.I had a typo...Euler's is it.